# Array of int getting a element wrong

Tags: java, integer

I have a class that I am using an int[] and I am getting a behavior that I don't know what is causing it. When I access the array with an index array[index] it returns the entire array. Here is a snippet of code to show you what is happening:

```
 public static int function(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    int i = low-1;
    System.out.println("Debug: " + arr[low] + " " + low + " " + high);
    return Math.min(i, arr[low]-arr[high]);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int[] arrangedArray = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int numberInputs = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
        while(numberInputs>0) {
            int size = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
            String[] arr1 = buffer.readLine().split(" ");
            Integer[] array1 = new Integer[size];
            for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
                array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);
            }
            arrangedArray = function(array1, 0, size-1);
            numberInputs--;
        }
        for(int k =0;k<arrangedArray.length;k++) {
            System.out.print(arrangedArray[k] + " ");
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
 So my array is populated with a loop from a string but I place it in int[] so 
 {2, 3, 4, 5,1}
 Debug: 23451 0 1
 I was testing with both "2 3 4 5 1" and 23451 still getting the same thing 
 but it is working now. I think it was an index or something.
```

When I would think this is getting the arr[0] element returning '2 0 1'. What am I doing that is causing this?

Comment: Show us a complete example (how ***exactly*** do you call this)?

Comment: While debugging, are you able to see the array having comma separated values ?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary The input is in the question now but it's not a delimited string I just separate with spaces.

Comment: I suspect in the line `array1[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);` is where the error is coming from. Because it is inside of a loop you are assigning each value (array1[i]) to another whole iteration value.

Comment: @beastlyCoder I have used this method for more than a year in dozens of different classes and never seen this error as it 'Integer' in this case instead of int so I will update then see if that corrects it.  It's one to one within in the array iterating over the entire element array.

Comment: You're _expecting_ the input data to look like `2 3 4 5 1`; but are you **sure** it's not  `23451` instead?

Comment: @April_Nara is your program even compiling ? I see the function has a return type int and you're not returning anything !!

Comment: @KevinAnderson I am getting a return and I am inputting the array with format correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still see issues while compiling. I am not sure why you're putting the wrong code here. instead of `Integer[] array1 = new Integer[size];`  put `int[] array1 = new int[size];` and you'll get the output with some more exceptions. But you'll atleast see the Debug line that you're printing.